# How to Save File Attachments By Date

Tags: vba, outlook

We get Outlook emails daily containing Excel files to analyze. The name always contains **"WPS"**.

I would like to run a script daily that saves the attachments, and organizes the attachments by the date on which they were sent.

The two ways I see the attachments being organized by date are:

- the Excel attachments are renamed with the date at the beginning of the file name
- they are put into dated folders.

I have an Outlook rule that grabs emails with **`"WPS"`** in the subject headline and contains an attachment.

Then the following script runs:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\anon\Downloads\Attachments\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

So now, I only have a folder with all the attachments from the beginning of time.

I am also concerned about duplicates, sometimes we are sent the same file if the sender makes the slightest change to it. Is there any way the most recent Excel attachment can be pulled if a duplicate is found?

Comment: Save it with Date & Time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python import os and write code to save file as current date and time which you can get by importing datetime module